# How to insert TextView data In mysql database using PHP in Android App?

Tags: java, android

I am new on android development i am using below code for getting longitude and latitude now i want to insert this textview field data in online mysql server database using php kindly suggest me any simple way for doing this.
Thanks In advance

```
'  import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
  LocationManager lm;
  TextView lt, ln;
  String provider;
  Location l;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ln=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lng);
   lt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
   //get location service
   lm=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   Criteria c=new Criteria();
   //criteria object will select best service based on
   //Accuracy, power consumption, response, bearing and monetary cost
   //set false to use best service otherwise it will select the default Sim network
   //and give the location based on sim network 
   //now it will first check satellite than Internet than Sim network location
   provider=lm.getBestProvider(c, false);
   //now you have best provider
   //get location
   l=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
   if(l!=null)
   {
     //get latitude and longitude of the location
     double lng=l.getLongitude();
     double lat=l.getLatitude();
     //display on text view
     ln.setText(""+lng);
     lt.setText(""+lat);
   }
   else
   {
    ln.setText("No Provider");
    lt.setText("No Provider");
   }
  }
   //If you want location on changing place also than use below method
   //otherwise remove all below methods and don't implement location listener
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
   {
    double lng=l.getLongitude();
    double lat=l.getLatitude();
    ln.setText(""+lng);
    lt.setText(""+lat);
   }

  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Http Post Request` for this.. this is the best way to do it.below is example-

```
  if(method == "POST"){
        // request method is POST
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

here in params you can send your data..

Answer (score 0):

just try to send data to php url by using get method like 
www.googleexmaple.com?name=abc
after that build php script at server side which will insert data to mysql database.
At android side use URLConnection or HTTPUrlConnection to hit urls and proper permissions to handle network operations.